# How to retrieve all paths of a source node without a target node using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is there a way to retrieve all paths from a source node without passing a target node?

Now I'm using `all_simple_paths(G,source,target)` but i have to specify 2 nodes, and for my problem is not possible because i'm workin with very large graphs (from 10 MB to 50MB).

Suppose i have this graph:
[input graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe3A2.png)

The starting nodes are the nodes with indegree equal to 0 (number 1, 7, 10 in figure) and the target nodes are the leaves (number 4, 5, 9, 10 in figures).

The output will be all paths from all starting nodes to all leaves nodes, for example:

`[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,5]
[1,6,9]
[7,8,9]`

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.  Can you give a sample input and output?  I'm having some trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Hi Joel, i just edited my question in order to show the input and the expected output.